# How is data stored and queried on the Namecoin blockchain, or any identity based blockchain like Emercoin

Tags: blockchain, namecoin

I am trying to research the identity based blockchains but i can't find how exactly they store their data on the blockchain so it can be easily queried. I can't seem to understand what the Namecoin op codes do.

Answer (score 0):

In the Emercoin, data stored in the ScriptPubKey of some transaction UTXO. Common idea - deploy data chunk, and operation OP_DROP thereafter. Or, 2 chunks, and OP_DROP2. To efficiently retrieve or update, data from NameTX scripts, stored in the nameindex db, indexed by name.